# Two SK's in one table

Tags: sql, join

I have a table with currency name, then currency sk.
I have a second table with currency_sk_from, currency_sk_to and conversion_rate.

I want to get a new table which combines this so I get currency_sk_from, currency_name, currency_sk_to, currency_name_to, conversion_rate

Can someone please help, when I tried to join it doubled the size of the second table.

Table one, looks like

```
currency name         Currency SK 
EUR           ,       1 
USD           ,       2 
SEK           ,       3
```

etc

Table two, looks like

```
currency_sk_from    currency_sk_to   conversion_rate
1        ,          2           ,    1.5
2        ,          1           ,    .6666
3        ,          1           ,    41
```

What I want is

```
currency_sk_from  currency_name   currency_sk_to    currency_name_to   conversion_rate
1        ,        EUR         ,   2           ,     USD          ,     1.5
2        ,        USD         ,   1           ,     EUR          ,     .6666
3        ,        SEK         ,   1           ,     EUR          ,     41
```

Comment: It all depends on what your joining on and what the structure of your data is like.  Can you provide sample data and the query you are running?

Comment: @JohnHenry . . . Does "sk" mean something or does it stand for Swedish Kroner?  Some sample data would really help convey what you want.

Comment: @GordonLinoff sk means a unique key which acts a unique identifier in table one

Comment: @GordonLinoff Aka Surrogate Key

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could try using subqueries instead of joins:-

```
SELECT CURRENCY_SK_FROM,
       (SELECT CURRENCY_NAME
            FROM CURRENCY
            WHERE CURRENCY_SK = CURRENCY_SK_FROM) AS CURRENCY_NAME,
       CURRENCY_SK_TO,
       (SELECT CURRENCY_NAME
            FROM CURRENCY
            WHERE CURRENCY_SK = CURRENCY_SK_TO) AS CURRENCY_NAME_TO,
       CONVERSION_RATE
    FROM CONVERSION_RATE_TABLE;
```

Comment: Your query will fail if there are duplicate rows in CURRENCY table, check this out http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/26e09e/7, you need to add DISTINCT in your subqueries like this http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/26e09e/8.

Comment: @snyder, that's true, but from the schema design it appears that `CURRENCY_SK` is a unique identifier on the `CURRENCY` table. It certainly ought to be if it isn't. I'd expect the `CURRENCY_SK_FROM` and `CURRENCY_FK_TO` columns to have a foreign key constraint into the `CURRENCY` table, and also to have `NOT NULL` constraints so that the currency names can always be found.

Comment: then what is the difference in the resultset of query which uses joins from the resultset your query, although I would prefer using subqueries as it is faster apparently but how is joining the tables doubling up the row if CURRENCY table doesn't have duplicates.

Comment: @snyder, I too was wondering why `DISTINCT` was necessary in the joined queries. The chief difference is that a duplicated entry without a `DISTINCT` would cause the sub-query version to fail ("sub-query selects more than one value"), rather than return spurious duplicates. This may be preferable, or not. Perhaps the questioner can help. I don't think the `DISTINCT` in the joined versions is going to fix the problem, either, if there are two rows in the `CURRENCY` table with the same `CURRENCY_SK` value but with different `CURRENCY_NAME`s.

Comment: Yes I agree that `DISTINCT` won't help here but what do you mean by spurious duplicates for eg. is there any duplication in [this](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/bd69c/2)

Comment: @snyder, yes, I'd call that a spurious duplicate, as the duplication is not present in the main queried table, but has been introduced by the decorative parts of the query (i.e. by attempting to find names for the currencies).

Comment: ok got it, everything will be fine if `CURRENCY_SK` is a primary key.

Answer (score 0):

If I have understood the question correctly below query will do the job :

```
  SELECT DISTINCT
    cskf.currency_sk_from, 
    cskfrom.currency_name, 
    cskf.currency_sk_to, 
    cskto.currency_name currency_name_to, 
    cskf.conversion_rate
  FROM
    currency_sk cskfrom
  JOIN
    currency_sk_from cskf ON 
    cskfrom.currency_sk = cskf.currency_sk_from
  JOIN
    currency_sk cskto ON 
    cskto.currency_sk = cskf.currency_sk_to
```

fiddle:http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/26e09e/2

Comment: This is the type of join which results in the duplicate set unfortunately @snyder

Comment: @John Henry Can you give some data for which the join query gives duplicate result ?

Answer (score 0):

To do this as a `select`, you require two joins to get both currencies:

```
select t2.currency_sk_from, fromname.currency as from_name,
       t2.currency_sk_to, toname.currency as to_name, t2.conversion_rate
from table2 t2 join
     table1 fromname
     on t2.currency_sk_from = fromname.sk join
     table1 toname
     on t2.currency_sk_to = toname.sk;
```

I don't actually think you need a new table.  This is easy enough to set up as a view to get the names of the currencies.

EDIT:

You should check for duplicates in `table1`, by doing:

```
select sk, count(*)
from table1
group by sk
having count(*) > 1
```

Comment: this results in doubling the amount of rows. I want to keep the rows the same as before the join, just with the two names added @Gordon_Linoff

Comment: @JohnHenry . . . This would only increase the number of rows if you have duplicates in `table1`.